# How I can run(call) a Automator Workflow in VBA excel for Mac

Tags: macos, ms-office, automator

I have a excel file and like run a VBA Macro that call a automator.workflow.

How I can do that ?

Comment: How to invoke a terminal command from VBA. This will get you started: cpearson.com/excel/ShellAndWait.aspx 

How to invoke a workflow from the terminal.

 - use the automater command
   man automater